# Show that $Z/\sqrt{n^{-1}\sum_{i=1}^n Y_i^2}$ converges in distribution

Tags: probability-theory

Let $Z, Y_1, Y_2, \dots, Y_n$ be iid Gaussian random variables. I have to show that $$\frac Z {\sqrt{n^{-1}\sum_{i=1}^n Y_i^2}}$$ converges in distribution.

Since $n$ only appears in the denumerator only, the convergence of the quantity there has to be verified. Indeed, $\frac{1}{\sqrt n}\sum_{i=1}^n(Y_i^2 - 1)$ converges in distribution to $\mathcal N(0, 2)$. However, that is not quite what is given here. I have therefore tried to rewrite the expression as follows: $$n^{-1}\sum_{i=1}^nY_i^2 = \frac{1}{\sqrt n} T_n + 1,$$ where $T_n = \frac{1}{\sqrt n}\sum_{i=1}^n(Y_i^2 - 1)$. So $T_n$ converges to $\mathcal N(0, 2)$ and the $1$ remains constant. But $\frac 1 {\sqrt n}T_n$ seems to convergence to a degenerate distribution as $\frac 1 {\sqrt n}$ converges to zero (Slutzky's theorem). Is my reasoning here correct? And what does this result imply for the original question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A short answer is this expression converges to $Z$. Effectively, $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n Y_i^2 \xrightarrow{n \to +\infty} 1$ almost surely (by law of large numbers) then you can deduce that $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^{-1}\sum_{i=1}^n Y_i^2}}$ converge to 1 almost surely. Consequently, $\frac{Z}{\sqrt{n^{-1}\sum_{i=1}^n Y_i^2}}$ converges to Z almost surely (and so converges to $Z$ in distribution).

If you want to find the asymptotic law of this expression, you can do as follows. From CLT, we have
$$\sqrt{n} \left( \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n Y_i^2 -E(Y^2)  \right) \xrightarrow{n \to +\infty} \mathcal{N}(0,V(Y^2))$$
or for $n \to +\infty$
$$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n Y_i^2 \sim 1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\mathcal{N}(0,2)$$
($\sim$ is "the equality in distribution")

By Taylor approximation, we have for $n \to +\infty$
\begin{align}
\frac{Z}{\sqrt{n^{-1}\sum_{i=1}^n Y_i^2}} &\sim \frac{Z}{(1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\mathcal{N}(0,2))^{\frac{1}{2}}} \\
&\sim Z(1-\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\mathcal{N}(0,2) + \mathcal{O}(\frac{1}{n})) \\
&\sim Z(1-\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\mathcal{N}(0,2) + \mathcal{O}(\frac{1}{n})) \\
&\sim Z-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2n}}ZT + \mathcal{O}(\frac{1}{n})) \\
\end{align}
where $Z,T$ are two iid gaussian random variables.